# npm install gives ssl error on docker jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, portainer

Running docker jenkins instance and trying to run the following command:

```
npm install --cache-min 9999
```

Following Error:

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://blahblahblah.com/api/npm/npmjs-repos/settings failed, reason: write EPROTO 140625881564992:error:14094410:SSL 
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl
/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-19T16_06_12_164Z-debug.log
Post stage

node -v  :: v10.16.3

npm -v   :: 2.15.11
```

## DOCKERFILE

```
RUN npm install protractor@^5.0.0 -g &&\
    npm install jasmine@^2.5.2 -g &&\
    npm install jasmine-reporters@^2.2.0 -g &&\
    npm install jasmine-spec-reporter@^3.1.0 -g &&\
    npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter@0.0.6 -g &&\
    npm install typescript@^2.0.7 -g &&\
    npm install axios@0.18.0 -g &&\
    webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: what image did you use?
can you give more of your Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Comment: Provided @TreantBG

Comment: i was looking more to see FROM what image did you create yours.
Can you give me the very beginning plse